# How Can I Set Anchor Text as Current on Containing DIV Click?

Tags: jquery, css, list

I have 3 `li` items creating a horizontal menu.

```
<div class="tab-container">
<ul class="tab-items">
  <li class="one">
    <a class="" href="#tab1">tab1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="two current">
    <a class="" href="#tab2">tab2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="three">
  <a class="current" href="#tab3">tab3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am using the following `JS` to add a current class to the active `li`:

```
 $(".tab-container ul li:first-child").addClass("current");
        $('.tab-container ul li').click(function () {
            $('.tab-container ul li').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });
```

This works great for what I am trying to achieve for the styling purposes of this `ul`.  The issue is that if a user clicks onto the `li` area that does not include the text, then they `JS` script will add the `current` class to the `li`, but not to the `a`.  How can I adjust or add to the `JS` to set the `a` of the `li` as `current` too in this instance?

---

UPDATE:

The tabs that are displayed based on this `ul` selection are selected depending on which `a` is set to `current`.  For example, I have the following `CSS` on the `current` item:

```
.tab-container ul li a.current{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Right now, if I click on the backing image of the `ul`:

```
.tab-container ul li.two{
background: url(../images/tab.png) no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
padding: 16px 92px;
position: relative;
}
```

then I can have the `li` show the `current` state, but the first `tab` will still be `active`.  So, I need a `JS` update which will actually select the `a` of the `current` class `li` when the user does not actually click on the anchor text.

Comment: you want the current class on <a> or <li> ?

Comment: @Oliboy50 I need it on both, but please see the update to the question for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add current class to both `a` and `li` tags (which is not a good idea IMHO):

```
$('.tab-container ul li').click(function () {
    $('.tab-container ul li, .tab-container ul li > a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).children('a').addBack().addClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want
http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/KSe94/5/

HTML

```
<div class="tab-container">
<ul class="tab-items">
  <li class="one">
    <a class="" href="#tab1">tab1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <a class="" href="#tab2">tab2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="three">
  <a class="" href="#tab3">tab3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(".tab-container ul li:first-child").addClass("current");
        $('.tab-container ul li').click(function () {
            $('.tab-container ul li').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });
```

CSS

```
li {
    float: left;
     list-style: none outside none;
}
li > a {
    padding: 40px;
}
li.current{background:red;}
```

Comment: yes, but I need this to actually set the `a` as `current` when the user clicks near the text too.  I'll add more notes to question to help explain.

Comment: please see the update to the question for more details.